# Check condition before execution

Tags: mysql

I've a Mysql Database with a table containing all scripts executed on the database.
I run all scripts directly in sql and I'd like to check in my script if someone already run the script.

In Sql Server I could have do this :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[LogScript] WHERE NomScript = 'MyScriptName')
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Warning : The script ''MyScriptName'' have already been runned on the database.'
  RETURN
END
```

As you can't use IF in Mysql, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `IF` *is* available in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

Comment: Unfortunatly it's not outside stored procedure :
    The IF statement for stored programs implements a basic conditional construct

Comment: how do you make sure that a script did not get started from somewhere else after the select and before you launch it?

Comment: i add it in the logscript table after testing if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

```
IF 1= (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[LogScript] WHERE NomScript = 'MyScriptName')
THEN
--Do something
--PRINT 'Warning : The script ''MyScriptName'' have already been runned on the database.';
END IF
```

```
select 'Warning : The script ''MyScriptName'' have already been runned on the database.'
FROM [dbo].[LogScript] WHERE NomScript = 'MyScriptName'
```

You can also Use **[Case](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)**

```
CASE (select  1 FROM [dbo].[LogScript] WHERE NomScript = 'MyScriptName')
WHEN 1 THEN --Statement
END CASE
```

Comment: I doubt whether you can use **Print**

Comment: i've already read it, and as it said, you can use IF statement inside a stored procedure, but you can't do it outside.
It's why i'm looking for a workaround

Comment: `CASE WHEN` seems to have the same issue than `IF`, i can make it work inside a stored procedure, but can't outside.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reinvent the wheel, have a look at [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/).

It basically does this for you, and you can integrate it into your build.

I've used it and would use it again (in fact I would insist on it).